# Plotting a sum in R Studio

Tags: r, plot

I am trying to plot the following function in R Studio using the curve function as follows:

```
loglikelihood.func = function(x, mu){
n = length(x)
n*mu - sum(x) - sum(exp(mu)/(exp(x)))
}

curve(expr = loglikelihood.func(x = data, mu), xname = "mu", from 
= 0, to = 15)
```

Now, I have a vector of data that contains 50 data points and in the function, it is currently summing both mu and x (my data) i.e. sum(exp(mu)/(exp(x))) is equivalent to sum(exp(mu))/sum(exp(x))

I want my function to work so that I have the fraction sum for each different data point in x while keeping mu constant i.e. exp(mu)/exp(x1) + exp(mu)/exp(x2) + exp(mu)/exp(x3) + ...   and repeat this for each separate mu when it plots in the curve function.

If I change my function to exp(mu)/sum(exp(x)) it's doing exp(mu)/[exp(x1)+exp(x2)+...] which is not what I want. Can someone offer some advice here?

Edit:
This is a subset of my data,

```
data = c(8.5,8.9,9.1,8.9,8.4,9.7,9.1,9.6,8.7,9.3,9.6,9.3,8.7,9.0,8.8,8.9,8.9,12.2)
```

Comment: We're missing something. This suggests that you have a variable named `data`. Are you certain `curve` has something to do with this? It seems like it may be just in your function. Can you provide some sample input, your *expected* output of those numbers (calculated on a calculator if needed), and the actual output.

Comment: I am not sure whether the problem is occurring when I plot it in the curve function or whether it is an error in the programming of my function. If I evaluate my function at some numbers e.g. loglikelihood.func(x = data, mu = 9) I recieve an output that is corrrect i.e. around -100. However when I plot it in the curve function I get stupidly large negative numbers. I have added my data to the post above.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I get this right... But `curve()` can't do as much by itself. You can define your function:

```
loglikelihood.func = function(x, mu) {
  length(x) * mu - sum(x) - sum(exp(mu)/(exp(x)))
}
```

Then define a range (for x) over which you'd like to plot it, and specify the limits (xlim, ylim) on a first plot. If you don't want to have a sequence, you can use your data instead.

```
xrange <- seq(from=1, to=10, by = 0.1)
plot(x=xrange, y = sapply(xrange, function(x) loglikelihood.func(x, mu=0)), 
     xlim = c(1, 10), 
     ylim = c(-10, 0),
     type = "l")
```

Then add other curves, specifying different mu's:

```
lines(x=xrange, y = sapply(xrange, function(x) loglikelihood.func(x, mu=1)))
lines(x=xrange, y = sapply(xrange, function(x) loglikelihood.func(x, mu=2)))
```

(More practical doing with a loop if you don't need extra graph parameters)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I don't think I've explained my problem well enough, but I'll have a fiddle with what you have done.